# Counting the number of objects in an array where the path is deeply nested

Tags: python

I want to count the number of objects in an array. The first one is easy `len(d['line_of_businesses'])` but it isn't obvious how from the example below I would count how many objects are in the array called `commercial_situations` which is 3 deep. Thanks, Matt

```
data = {
"line_of_businesses": [
{
  "asset_groups": {
    "commercial_situations": [
      {
        "asset_id": "d222cecf-af58-465a-9506-e76807d7d9tf"
      }
     ]
    }
   }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will do the job for you. For More Info [Click Here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/nested-dictionary)

```
data = {
"line_of_businesses": [
{
  "asset_groups": {
    "commercial_situations": [
      {
        "asset_id": "d222cecf-af58-465a-9506-e76807d7d9tf"
      },
      {
        "asset_id": "1222cecf-af58-465a-9506-e76807d7d9tf"
      }
     ]
    }
   }
 ]
}
print(len(data['line_of_businesses'][0]['asset_groups']['commercial_situations']))
```

How it works? First get the items in `line_of_buisness` then this is an array so we need its first element so `[0]` and inside this we need data of `asset_groups` so `['asset_groups']` and then inside this we need `commercial_situations`.

Comment: thank you, that worked a treat - easy when you know how.

Comment: This works but IMO is not scalable